# Properties in Spring 4 with @Value in class extended from GenericFilterBean

Tags: java, spring

OK. So the problem is when I run the application in debug mode it does get in the setter for `enabled` and it is set to false, but when `doFilter` is called `enabled` is always true.

I've removed some comments for clarity ;-).

```
public class CorsFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private String allowedOrigins = "^(https?://([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*\\.)?(local|localhost)(:[0-9]+)?$";

    private boolean enabled = true;

    @Value("${cors.enabled}")
    public void setEnabled(String enabled) {
        if (enabled != null) {
            this.enabled = enabled.matches("^[ \\t]*(true|1|yes)[ \\t]*$");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        if (isEnabled()) {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            String requestOrigin = req.getHeader("Origin");
            // ignore when origin empty or not given or not matched
            if (requestOrigin != null && !requestOrigin.isEmpty() && requestOrigin.matches(getAllowedOrigins())) {
                res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", requestOrigin);
                res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept,Authorization,Origin,Content-type");
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public String getAllowedOrigins() {
        return allowedOrigins;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

In beans.xml:

```
<bean id="CorsFilter" class="saas.web.filter.CorsFilter" />
```

In properties file:

```
cors.enabled=false
```

In web.xml

```
<!-- CORS -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>saas.web.filter.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual filter used by the webapplication will not be the one created by spring in your current configuration.  You have to use a [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) to use the bean created by spring.

Changing your filter in the web.xml file as follows might do the trick:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: Well actually it is created by Spring, but there are 2 instances of the filter. One managed by Spring the other by the web container.

Comment: I love you. It works :-). You wouldn't believe how many hours I spent trying to resolve this...